# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Person", referenced from:

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I have had this app running for a couple of years, now, and was just adding in some fields in the data model and then generating NSManagedOjects (This wasn't even one of the classes I changed.) Now, I can't get rid of this error. I have checked that Person.m and Person+CoreDataProperties.m are in the target. I have structured this class the same as all of the others. I just can't figure out where the bug is.

I am running Xcode 9.2. The Target platform is iOS 9 (many of my friends are still on this version). I'm on MacOS 10.13.2. I have spent three full days trying everything I can think of. I have deleted derived data, started and stopped, Xcode, cleaned the project, etc.

Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that made no sense to me: I included the CoreDataClass .m files in the target, and everything worked. I have always excluded them in the past, and have excluded them for the other classes.

Comment: Sorry I missed your point about target inclusion of the model class.  Glad you found a solution.  It's no surprise that you need CoreDataClass, and it is a surprise that you once didn't.  I'll leave my answer undeleted since it is a common cause for linker problems.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is that the class defining Person is not included in the target that you're building.  In the file navigation pane of Xcode (on the far left), select Person.m.  On the File Inspector pane (far right, select the icon that looks like a square with a folded corner), look at the "Target Membership" section.  Your target ought to be checked.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question: it is included in the target. I have checked that all of the files that should be in the target are "checked" for the target. I have checked this countless times. Also, this is not a new class - it has been in the app for years. That's what's so frustrating!

Comment: Just for fun, I unchecked the class Person from the target and compiled. Oddly, ALL of my NSManaged classes showed up as undefined. I systematically added each one back, and still ALL of my classes are getting the undefined error.

Comment: One more thing: after checking, unchecking, checking the targets, I ended up with four classes that were undefined. All four were recently modified in the data model and I had run the "create NSManagedObject" process on all four. Still scratching my head.